# Smarty equivalent for str_split()

Tags: prestashop, smarty, strsplit

Im looking for an equivalent for str_split() in Smarty as {php}{/php} looks like deprecated and not very clean.
I came across explode but it needs a delimiter and what I'm trying to get is:

```
1/2/3/4/5
```

from

```
$chars = str_split(12345);
foreach($chars as $char){
    echo $char . '/';
}
```

But in a Smarty environment.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex based approach:

```php
$chars = "12345";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/", "/", $chars);
echo $output;  // 1/2/3/4/5
```

Comment: Nice one thanks! In a Smarty environment I got the job done with: {"12345"|regex_replace:"/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/":"/"}

Comment: I also needed to reproduce this with javascript like: `....replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/, "/")` which works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari because of lookbehind not being supported that browser yet. Any better idea for js ?

Comment: @David For JS use a capture group: `str.replace(/(\d)(?=\d)/, "$1.")`

Answer (score 0):

You can user function .replace in JS pls check the following sample:

var text = '1 2 3 4 5',

text = text.replace(/\s+/g, '/');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =text;